# Acoustics - transition between free field to wave guided propagation of ultrasound

Tags: acoustics

Is there a general formula involving wavelength, transducer diameter and tube diameter that shows where free field propagation transitions to wave guided?

Comment: A diagram would really help understand this question. Can you add one?

Comment: Not worth it. 8 months is a long time.

Comment: Ok, well, that makes [your meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/a-separate-se-site-for-experimental-physics) a little hard to take seriously. I'm literally sitting here trying to help answer this and you're telling me you don't have the motivation to help me help you. Good luck.

Comment: @DanielSank I no longer need the information because we hacked it to "good enough" without any theory. This is a commercial project and time is money. The information would have been valuable at the time, but not after the problem is solved (solved = good enough). Although I am working with MSc and PhD students from Imperial I am not an academic, and I have a time critical job that I get paid to do.

Comment: I understand your situation. If you need help faster in the future I would recommend setting a bounty, or even advertising your question in the chat room. This is the sort of question I would really like to try to answer! Keep in mind that this isn't an easy question at all; It's not something we learn about in school, so it's at a disadvantage in terms of getting answers. Starting a new site for experimentalists will not help this situation in the slightest. You're way better off advertising and usin the bounty system.

Comment: To prove my point: [here is a (theory) question which was ignored until I set a bounty](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155360/what-information-is-contained-in-the-quantum-spectral-density), after which I got a good answer.